# Remove cell highlight wont work

Tags: excel, vba

Have a chemical inventory  that open a txtbox each for Room, Shelf, Bottle where i scan the 3 items.  Once scanned they are added to the spreadsheet at cells  M2, O2, Q2 respectively and the cell color changed to yellow.  Have buttons for new botte which clears the  bottletxtbox for inpupt.

Have tried various ways to remove the cell coloring using xlNone, -4105, xlAutomatic and 0 to a Interior.ColorIndex= Statement and it does not work any help would be appreciated

```
 Option Explicit
'when i added code to these it would typ R on the textBox and M240 elsewhere without code it works
'Original program did not work had Explicitly programmed the SetFocus to advance from input box to input box and
'set a varialbe RoomCode to house the barcode but id did not work properly.



Private Sub ButtonNewBottle_Click()

    'Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone '-4105,xlAutomatic,0
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    TextBox3.Text = ""

    Cells(2, 17).Value = "   "
    TextBox3.SetFocus  'sends the focus to text box 3 to read another Bottle barcode

    Call TextBox3_Change

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonNewRoom_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    Cells(2, 13).Value = " "

    TextBox2.Text = ""
    Cells(2, 15).Value = "   "

    TextBox3.Text = ""
    Cells(2, 17).Value = "   "

    TextBox1.SetFocus  'sends the focus to text box 3 to read another

    Call TextBox1_Change
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonNewShelf_Click()
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    Cells(2, 15).Value = "   "

    TextBox3.Text = ""
    Cells(2, 17).Value = "   "

    TextBox2.SetFocus  'sends the focus to text box 3 to read another

    Call TextBox2_Change
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   Cells(2, 13).Value = TextBox1.Text
   Cells(2, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
   Cells(2, 15).Value = TextBox2.Text
   Cells(2, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    Cells(2, 17).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Cells(2, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

End Sub
```

Comment: Could there be conditional formating on those cells?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub NoBack()
    With Range("Q2")
        If .FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
            .FormatConditions.Delete
        End If
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope that did not work either.  Question where do you put this Sub in the module or in the user form code for the newbottle?